Create Invoice Attachment using API call in Odoo 17
I am currently working on sending invoices via email using the Odoo 17 API from a Node.js server. I've managed to handle most of the tasks, but I encountered an issue when trying to send an invoice via email. Instead of being sent as an attachment, the invoice is included as a link in the email.
understand that to attach the invoice as a PDF file, I need to make an API call like this:
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "call",
    "params": {
        "service": "object",
        "method": "execute_kw",

        "args": [
            "{{db}}",
            "{{uid}}",
            "{{password}}",
            "ir.attachment",
            "create",
          [{
        "name": "Invoice.pdf", 
        "type": "binary",  
        "res_model": "account.move",
        "datas": "base64 data",
        "res_id": 17, 
        "mimetype": "application/pdf" 
      }]
        ]
    }
}

But first I need to somehow encode the data into base64 format. Is there an Odoo API method to directly encode the file? Or maybe it's possible that there's a setting in Odoo that could automatically add the invoice as an attachment when it's created, instead of manually handling the attachment via API?
Thanks in advance!

How do you send the mail? Usually invoice PDFs are saved automatically when rendered in context of a mail. For example using the account.move.send wizard. On the other hand, what is stopping you from encoding the data via node.js?

I think I can just use email templates. Then the attachment is being added automatically. The body of the API call is like this:
{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "call", "params": { "service": "object", "method": "execute_kw", "args": [ "{{db}}", "{{uid}}", "{{password}}", "mail.template", "send_mail", [12, 50], { "force_send": "True" } ] }, "id": 5 }
